# ¿como puedo actualizar la contraseña de laravel sin cerrar sesion?

Tags: laravel

quisiera poder actualizar la contraseña sin que me cierre la sesion , como podría evitar el cierre de sesion?Muchas gracias

Codigo :

```php
   public function updatePassword(Request $request){

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->password = Hash::make($request["password"]);
        $user->update();
        if($user){
            return redirect()->back()->with(["success" => "Contraseña actualizada exitosamente!"]);

        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with(["failed" => "Se produjo un error !"]);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo cree un controlador que solamente hace eso cambiar la contraseña:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Auth, Hash;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable;
 use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

 class ChangePasswordController extends Controller
{
public function index(): Renderable
{

  return view('users.password.change-password');
}

public function changePassword(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
      'current_password' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
      'password_confirmation' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

    if (!Hash::check($request->current_password, $user->password)) {
        return back()->withErrors('¡La contraseña actual no coincide!');
    }

    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->save();

    return back()->withSuccess('Contraseña cambiada correctamente');
  } 
 }
```

El método index devuelve un formulario con tres campos, contraseña actual, nueva contraseña y confirmar contraseña nueva.

El segundo método changePassword valida los datos, el usuario esta logeado, y la condicional verifica si la contraseñas nueva y confirmar su contraseña coinciden.

Por ultimo el facade Hash de Laravel proporciona hashing seguro de Bcrypt y Argon2 para almacenar contraseñas de usuarios, se guarda y regresa a la página anterior.